# Mobile Web application running when screen is off?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I'm considering building a mobile Web application,  using Jquery Mobile that will be used to track truck delivery.

I want to be able to periodically send gps coordinates back to the server?  Can this be done if the screen is off?

If not can some alternate approaches be suggested..

Answer (score 0):

If you are good in javascript and html you can go for phonegap. this framework will work like a native application and running from webview like browser. Since phonegap is a cross platform framework you can make your app compatible to many devices like windows phone, Apple, Android. To know more about phonegap or cordova click [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview)

And yes phonegap does many function or features that can customize your application in many way. for example "WAKE LOCK" which keeps your application awake till you force close it.

or if you are using browser you can not run your code for long since browser is a big application android or your mobile system will close it.